# Can RailsAPI with puma handle both XHR and websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, websocket, xmlhttprequest

So, I'm using my rails app as an API app only.
I have nginx frontend running.
I have set these up using docker.
My app uses XHR, but then I wanted to WebSocket.

Then I realized that I have to use 'puma' instead of 'thin'.

Now WebSocket is working, but XHR is not working anymore.

Is there any way that I can make both working?

So, what's happening with my XHR is that the response is empty now!!

Here I'm including the screenshot of my request...

[image]

**BUMP==========================================**

Here I'm adding my `Dockerfile` for my rails app, and the `docker-compose.yml` for the whole environment. And rails-app is the only image I create from my docker setup. And just in case, I'll include my nginx `default.conf` file as well.

```
# rails-api/Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.5.0

# Set environment.
ENV \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  TERM=xterm-color \
  HOME=/usr/src/rails-api

# Install base packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  curl \
  git \
  wget \
  libqt4-dev \
  imagemagick \
  ghostscript \
  postgresql-client

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install ruby gems
RUN gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc \
  bundler \
  rubygems-update

# Bundle install gems in the tmp cash
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

# Define the working director
WORKDIR /usr/src/rails-api

ADD . /usr/src/rails-api

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/rails-api/tmp/pids

CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And here is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services: 
  #
  # Postgresql is a required service to run the stack
  #
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - "~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.6:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  #
  # Redis
  #
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.8
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=65535
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  #
  # API is used for general development
  #
  development_api:
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - WEB_HOST=http://dockerhost:1000/
      - RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
    image: myawesomeapp/rails-api
    command: ["rails", "server","-b","0.0.0.0","-P","tmp/pids/development.pid"]
    volumes:
      - ./rails-api:/usr/src/rails-api
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
  #
  # Sidekiq for background job processing
  #
  development_cron:
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - WEB_HOST=http://dockerhost:1000/
    image: myawesomeapp/rails-api
    volumes:
      - ./rails-api:/usr/src/rails-api
    links:
      - development_api
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
  #
  # NGINX hosted javascript client
  #
  development_web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./myawesomeapp/public:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./myawesomeapp/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - 1000:80
    links:
      - development_api
      - development_cron
```

And here is the my `nginx/default.config`

```
# myawesomeapp/nginx/default.config
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    location = / {
    }

    location = /index.html {
    }

    location /img {
    }

    location /css {
    }

    location /js {
    }

    location /tos {
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://$http_host/#$request_uri last;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in nginx or your app? Can you make XHR and Websocket requests directly to the ruby app? Can you add any Dockerfiles and docker commands you are using to set this environment up (or `docker-compose.yml`)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it seems there is no error messages neither from nginx, nor from my rails app. But yes I can make XHR and Websocket requests from my nginx to rails app. It's just XHR doesn't have any response body even if the request status 200 is returned, and websocket is simply working great(sending out or getting data). And yup! I'll add dockerfile and the docker-compose here as well!